Google Wallet Pass JWT and API
We are investigating how we can build a backend API for the generation of generic passes for a user to add to their Google Wallet.
For the investigation we are referencing the Google .NET example implementation here: https://github.com/google-wallet/rest-samples/blob/main/dotnet/DemoGeneric.cs
In this example there is a method called CreateObject that builds the GenericPass and uses WalletobjectsService to insert the pass.
There is also a method called CreateJWTNewObjects that builds the GenericPass and then incorporates it into a signed JWT token and uses this to build a URL for the user to use to add it to their wallet.
What we're not clear on is are these simply two different ways of creating a pass or are both process required? I.e. You need to use WalletobjectsService and create the JWT or it is enough to simply create the JWT.

CreateObject only creates the pass within your google account.  CreateJWTNewObjects creates a JWT that you put as the href to your "Add to Wallet" button, so the pass is created and assigned to the user who clicked the button.

That doesn't really make sense with the example code at https://github.com/google-wallet/rest-samples/blob/main/dotnet/DemoGeneric.cs as the CreateJWTNewObjects method encodes all the pass information in the JWT.
Why would you do that if you've already provided all that information via the WalletobjectsService?

I think I now see that these are two different ways of creating a pass.
If you use WalletobjectsService to insert the pass then you have more control over the pass creation and avoid exposing pass data in the URL.
in this instance the save URL would be https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{issuerId}.{objectId}
If you generate the pass via a JWT token you avoid having to interact with Google APIs directly but the pass data is exposed in the URL.
In this instance the save URL would be https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{signedJwt}
